# ASP.Net Forms page - capture HTML after javascript runs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf

I've got an ASP.Net forms application that has a number of data collection pages on it. We'd like a feature that would go through all of the pages for the logged in user, and capture all of the HTML of the pages, and stick it into a PDF.

Right now, for each page, I'm calling

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
Context.Server.Execute ( pageName, sw );
```

The issue is, the page has some client-side JavaScript that calculates totals on the page. We need to capture the HTML after the JS script has calculated the totals, so that it shows properly on the PDF.

Is there any way I can either fire the JS when the page is done loading, or some other way that we can do this, all on the server side?

Comment: Are you using any javscript frameworks or just vanilla js?

Comment: Just vanilla javascript